# Source code save plot R; gWidgets

Tags: r, gwidgets

I am looking for the source of the `save` function in the pop up menu in a `ggraphics()`.  Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The save code is in the svalue<- method. For gWidgetsRGtk2 it is available on r-forge. The github site would have gWidgets2RGtk2 code, but there is no such function there. The following is my guess as to what you are looking for,  but it is a hack so use with caution. (I'm pretty sure the window can't have any other window covering it.)

```
  da <- getWidget(obj)
   wh <- daGetWidthHeight(da)
   da.w <- wh[1]
   da.h <- wh[2]
   pixbuf <- gdkPixbufGetFromDrawable(src=da$window, src.x=0, src.y=0,
                                      dest.x=0, dest.y=0, width=da.w,        height=da.h)


   out <- try(pixbuf$Save(filename = filename,type=extension), silent=TRUE)
```